# how to serialize dataframe to a protobuff in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, protocol-buffers

I have gone through many posts [1](https://github.com/dotarj/protobuf-net-data), [2](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) but could not find anywhere to convert a dataframe to a protobuf in scala. Any pointers, please.

Comment: You could convert dataframe to array and then convert to protobuf, i don´t know if it is possible to convert in 1 step

Comment: What do these "1" and "2" post have in common with "serialising data-frame using protobuff" ?